# Applying multiple functions to a list of dataframes with lapply R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of dataframes that contains assay data of various elements/compounds.  Each dataframe represents a specific element.  Each dataframe consists results from 10 labs but with differing number of results provided from each lab, most have 6 results per element but some have 10.

A sample of my list of dataframes below

```
df <- list(Al2O3 = structure(list(Determination_No = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `2` = c(2.04, 2.07, 2.05, 2.07, 2.1, 2.08, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `3` = c(2.08, 2.1, 2.08, 2.13, 2.1, 2.08, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), `4` = c(2.08, 2.08, 2.09, 2.06, 2.08, 2.07, 2.07, 
2.06, 2.08, 2.08), `5` = c(2.11, 2.09, 2.1, 2.08, 2.09, 2.09, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `7` = c(2.06, 2.05, 2.04, 2.05, 2.04, 2.03, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `8` = c(2.078, 2.065, 2.057, 2.063, 2.067, 2.066, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `10` = c(2.191776681, 2.153987428, 2.153987428, 
2.097303548, 2.116198175, 2.116198175, NA, NA, NA, NA), `12` = c(2.24, 
2.08, 2.12, 2.15, 2.15, 2.15, NA, NA, NA, NA), `36` = c(2.07, 
2.082, 2.048, 2.046, 2.086, 2.069, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), As = structure(list(Determination_No = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `2` = c(0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 
0.001, NA, NA, NA, NA), `3` = c(0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.001, 
0.002, NA, NA, NA, NA), `4` = c(0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 
0.002, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.003), `5` = c(0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 
0.001, 0.001, 0.002, NA, NA, NA, NA), `7` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `8` = c(NA, 0.001, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `10` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `12` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `36` = c(0.0053, 0.0053, 0.0053, 
    0.00454, 0.0053, 0.0053, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), Ba = structure(list(Determination_No = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `2` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    `3` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.001, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `4` = c(0.004, 
    0.003, 0.003, 0.004, 0.003, 0.002, 0.004, 0.002, 0.005, NA
    ), `5` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.003, NA, NA, NA, NA), `7` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `8` = c(0.002, 0.003, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0.002, NA, NA, NA, NA), `10` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), `12` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), `36` = c(0.00089566, 0.00089566, 0.00089566, 0.00089566, 
    0.00089566, 0.00089566, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)))
```

I want to calculate then Z score for each element across each dataframe. If there are no Zscore outliers then I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation and report as my consensus value and uncertainty.  If there are Z score outliers then I want to calculate the Median and MScore (modified Z score) to be reported as consensus value and uncertainty.

Additionally, when calculating MScore if more than 25% of my labs have a MScore greater than my threshold (3.5) then I want uncertainty left blank.

Below is my code to calculate the ZScore which works and I can apply to my list of dataframes and assigned to a new list of dataframes.

```
ZMax <- 3
SampleZScores <- function(x,...){
  unlistdata <- unlist(x[-1])
  GrandMean <- mean(unlistdata,na.rm = T)
  GrandSD <- sd(unlistdata,na.rm=T)
  ZScore <- abs(((x[-1])-GrandMean)/GrandSD) #calculate the Z sore and make absolute
  return(ZScore)
}


ZScores <- lapply(df, function(x) SampleZScores(x,na.rm=T))
```

The next bit of code is attempting to write a function that includes the Zscore function as well as nested if statements trying to apply my problem.

```
scores_na <- function(x, ...) {
  not_na <- !is.na(x)
  scores <- rep(NA, length(x))
  scores[not_na] <- outliers::scores(na.omit(x), ...)
  scores
}

FinalStats <- function(x,...){ 
  Zscores <- lapply(x, function(x) SampleZScores(x,na.rm=T))
  if(Zscores < ZMax){
    LabMean <- mapply(mean, x[-1], na.rm = T) #Calculate Mean by columns
    LabMean[is.infinite(LabMean)] <- NA
    Lab.GrandMean <- mean(LabMean,na.rm=T)
    ConsensusValue <- Lab.GrandMean
    
    SD.All <- unlist(y[-1])
    Uncertainty <- sd(SD.All, na.rm = T)
  }else{ 
    #Calculate Concensus Value for upto 25% outlier MScore
    LabMedian <- mapply(median, x[-1], na.rm = T) #Calculate Median by columns
    LabMedian[is.infinite(LabMedian)] <- NA #convert any Inf values to NA
    
    MScore <- as.vector(round(abs(scores_na(labmedians, "mad")), digits = 2))
    Mexceed <- length(MScore[MScore > MscoreMax]) 
  }
    if(Mexceed > 0.25*length(x[-1])){ #if more than 25% of the columns exceed MScore assign NA
      Uncertainty <- NA
    }else{ #otherwise calculate the MScore and assign to the Uncertainty
      Uncertainty <- as.vector(round(abs(scores_na(labmedians, "mad")), digits = 2))
    }
  
    ConsensusValue <- median(LabMedian,na.rm=T)#Use the median value if consensus value when Zscore exceeded  

  FinalValues <- cbind(ConsensusValue,Uncertainty) #combined the desired Info
  
  return(FinalValues)     
}  

CatergoreisStats <- lapply(df,FinalStats)
```

I get the following error code but unsure which part is causing the problem.

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
```

Is the problem with my nested if statement in my function or the way I am trying to apply the lapply function to my custom function?

I can see that my Zscore ends up with lots of NA mostly due to missing information.  This causes an issue with my If statement, so I need a work around so that I can use an if statement on values that contain NA

Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `debugonce`? the first step in `FinalStats` makes a list which you try to do `if (Zscores < ZMax)`, and `Zscores` is a list which cannot be coerced to a double for the conditional

Comment: @rawr I am not sure I follow what you are saying.  Zscores is a list so lapply should work should it not?

Comment: yes and `as.numeric(Zscores)` fails which happens when you try `if (Zscores < ZMax)`

Comment: @rawr so I need to make these values numeric ?